# dot "." and ".." hidden files taking up space in empty directory

Tags: filesystems, ls

When I `ls -ltr` on the `danny` directory, it shows that the `quarantine` directory size as a little over 2 megabytes. Then I go to the quarantine directory and do an `ls`, and it has nothing in it - it is empty. However if I use the *a flag* to list hidden files the "." (this directory) has 2 megabytes in it and the parent ".." has 90kilobytes. Moreover `ls -ltra .*` shows nothing but the two dotted files (this and parent directory) ". .." .

Removing the quarantine directory and recreating a new one in its place wipes out the invisible megabytes shown. works. Moreover the `ls -ltra` shows a zero for both the parent and "this" dot directory. So the problem is solved. However, I don't know what is causing this.

There are no files in the directory to run lsof on. There are no files in the directory, but is shows that it is holding 2 megabytes filespace.

```
casperrd@usaHOST02 1016$ ls -ltra /come/and/playwithus/danny/quarantine
total 2380
drwxr-xr-x 2 casperrd casper 2330624 Jul 11  2016 .
drwxr-xr-x 4 casperrd casper   90112 Oct 20 05:36 ..
casperrd@usaHOST02 1017$
```

Comment: note that there's no unit called "mb" (millibit?)

Comment: I cannot reproduce your listing: according to the directory sizes shown, the total size on disc of the directories listed should be 2366, with the normal I/O block size of 4096. To be accurate, I could reproduce the listing, but only with a block size of 14366, which seems unlikely. You can verify the directory details with `stat /come/and/playwithus/danny/quarantine`.

Answer (score 0):

Unix directories never shrink. 
The directory must have *once* been filled with files
whose names added up to 2 megabytes. 
Even when those files were deleted, the directory retained its size.

Deleting and recreating the directory is the only way to fix this.